# How to prevent body scrolling but allow scroll content and stay footer on the bottom?

Tags: html, css, layout

The structure of page is header, two columns (one fixed) and footer.
I need this functionality:
Header staying in top of screen and not scrollable.
Left column is fixed width and height is 100% of screen. It includes two rows. The top row is fixed width, fills all height and scrollable, the bottom is fixed width and height.
Right column is scrollable. 
Footer is in right column and scrollable together with right column but if right column is short then staying in bottom of screen.
The problem is the scrolling going to the body of page. Only right column with footer should be scrollable. And footer is not staying on the bottom of screen when right column has no content.

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.header,
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
}

#leftcontent {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

#lefttop {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 100px;
  background: aqua;
}

#leftbottom {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  background: pink;
}

#rightcol {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

#rightcontent {
  background: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> header content </div>
<div class="content">
  <div id="leftcontent">
    <div id="lefttop">left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br
      />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br /> left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br
      />left looonnnnng<br />
    </div>
    <div id="leftbottom">
      left bottom content<br />left bottom content<br />left bottom content<br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightcol">
    <div id="rightcontent">
      right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br /> right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right
      cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br
      />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right
      cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />
    </div>
    <div class="footer"> footer content </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I cannot use Bootstrapper because using Telerik and prefer using CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working solution. http://jsfiddle.net/isadykov/s37z0pfu/40/
If you increase the height of window that right content is shorter then footer will stay on the bottom of screen. If you decrease the height of window that right content is not fitting then footer is pushed to the bottom of page and scrollbar appearing.

```css
body, html, form { padding:0; margin:0; height:100%;  }
.header, .footer{ width:100%;  background:#ccc; text-align:center;  }
.header {height: 50px;}
.content{ height: calc(100% - 50px); background:lightgray;}
#leftcontent{ width:300px; float:left; height:100%;  background:blue;}
#lefttop {width:300px; overflow-y:auto; position: fixed; top:50px;bottom:100px;background:aqua;}
#leftbottom {width:300px; height:100px; position: fixed; bottom:5px;  background: pink;}
#rightcol{ overflow-y:auto; height: 100%;  background:green;}
#rightcontent { min-height:100%; margin: 0 auto -50px;background:magenta; }
.footer {height: 50px;}
.push {height: 50px; }
```

```html
<div class="header"> header content </div>
<div class="content">
  <div id="leftcontent">    
    <div id="lefttop">left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />
       left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />left looonnnnng<br />
    </div>
    <div id="leftbottom">
       left bottom content<br />left bottom content<br />left bottom content<br />
    </div>     
  </div>
  <div id="rightcol">
    <div id="rightcontent">    
        right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />
        right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br /> cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />right cccooonntent<br />    
       <div class="push" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"> footer content </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to investigate [CSS Position property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

To fix your header at the top you can say

```
.header
{
  position: fixed;
}
```

However this will make your header div placed independent from rest of the page. Thus, to prevent an overlap, you should do:

```
.content{
  margin-top: 50px; /*The hight of the header div*/
}
```

Then, to keep footer at the bottom you can assign height of the right content accordingly, regardless of its content, then make it scrollable like this:

```
#rightcontent
{
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I would separate the rule for header and footer.
Overall, the changed part of your css should look like this.

```
.header
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.content{
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.footer{
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

#rightcontent
{
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: With this settings there are two vertical scrollbars on the right. I removed second scroll bar from "rightcontent" but footer still not staying on the bottom of page if height of page is bigger than "rightcontent".